# Javascript: Iterate through array of URLs and open, then close at defined interval

Tags: javascript, settimeout, window.open

I have an array of URLs that I need to loop through and open in a new window.  However, I need to be able to set a timeout between each window's open and close.  In other words, the window should only stay open for a set interval, then move on to the next URL in the array.

The following code opens the windows, but only closes the first one.

```
        (function X() {
            document.getElementById("target").onclick = function () {

                var urlList = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.msn.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com'];
                var wnd;

                for (var i = 0; i < urlList.length; i++) {
                   wnd = window.open(urlList[i], '', '');

                    setTimeout(function () {
                        wnd.close();
                    }, 2000);

                }

            };
            return true;
        }
        )();
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `for loop` runs everything effectively all at once, so your code is opening all the windows at once, and then your close timeouts all launch 2 seconds later (all at the same time).

You need to have a timeout between each iteration of the array.

Here would be a way to do this:

```
var urlList = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.msn.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com'];
var wnd;
var curIndex = 0; // a var to hold the current index of the current url

function openWindow(){
    wnd = window.open(urlList[curIndex], '', '');
    setTimeout(function () {
         wnd.close(); //close current window
         curIndex++; //increment the index
         if(curIndex < urlList.length) openWindow(); //open the next window if the array isn't at the end
    }, 2000);
}

openWindow();
```

---

**EDIT:**  10 Years later (2024), it's worth noting that in order to open a new window/tab via JavaScript in any modern browser, the script has to be triggered by a user interaction.  A method like this one, will not actually open the window/tab.  Even if this loop were called in a click event handler, only the first iteration would work as subsequent calls to `window.open` would need to run in new click handlers.

Comment: This opens and closes the first window only.  The other URLs in the array are not opened.

Comment: probably because I have a typo in `openWIndow()`  make the "I" lowercase and it should work.

Comment: as of 2024 this does not work

Comment: @aryankarim - The code technically still works, but all modern browsers now require a user interaction (click) to trigger a new window (one user interaction per 1 new window) 
 - and that's definitely a good thing for us all!

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis you are right. I had to give the website PopUp and Redirect permission then it worked.