# HTML code to scroll through pdf files

Tags: html, url, pdf, settimeout

I am trying to develop a program that will switch between url locations every 10 seconds and then loop back after going to the last url.  Description below:

- Display url1 for 10 sec
- Display url2 for 10 sec
- Display url3 for 10 sec
- LOOP BACK TO URL (continuous loop)

I believe this can be done using settimeout and for loop.  I do not have a complete understanding of settimeout and java for that matter so that is where I am currently stuck at.  I have placed a code below but since I do not know how to use settimeout believe this is my first mistake.

If there is a better way to do this I am all ears.  I have been trying java for 3 days because it needed to be do for a project at work so I am brand new to it and probably over my head.

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>

"urls"

<script>
var myurl;

function urls()
{
    myurl=setTimeout(url1,0);
    myurl=setTimeout(url2,10000);
    myurl=setTimeout(url3,20000);
}

function url1()
{
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name=plugin src="http://files.asme.org/ICOMES/News/15876.pdf#pagemode=none&scrollbar=0&page=2" type="application/pdf".;
}

function url2()
{
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name=plugin src="http://www.tbp.org/pubs/Features/Su04McMasters.pdf#pagemode=none&scrollbar=0&page=2" type="application/pdf".;
}

function url3()
{
<embed width="100%" height="100%" name=plugin src="http://milproj.dc.umich.edu/publications/EngFlex_report/download/EngFlex%20Report.pdf#pagemode=none&scrollbar=0&page=2" type="application/pdf".;
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

edit:

```
<!DOCTYPE>
<html>
<body>
<script>
var urlList = ['http://www.google.com', 'http://www.msn.com', 'http://www.yahoo.com'];
var wnd;
var curIndex = 0; // a var to hold the current index of the current url

function openWindow(){
    wnd = window.open(urlList[curIndex], '', '');
    setTimeout(function () {
         wnd.close(); //close current window
         curIndex++; //increment the index
         if(curIndex < urlList.length) openWindow(); //open the next window if the array isn't at the end
    }, 2000);
}

openWindow();

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where do you need Java?

Comment: I might not need java.  When I was trying to find someone to help me I got recommended to talk with individuals who know Java.  Removed the java keyword.

Comment: You would want JavaScript and this type of question is answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23701987/javascript-iterate-through-array-of-urls-and-open-then-close-at-defined-interv

Comment: Thank you Kenneth Clark & @Veselin Davidov.  If I can get either one of these to work I will cry.  Been reading posts for probably 30 hours the last two days and didn't get anywhere.  Thank you for at least starting me in the right direction.

Comment: @KennethClark I tried the format and it only opened up google.com and did not go from there.  Did I properly place the code?  Please view the edit above.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's not java. It's javascript ;) 
You can do one iframe in an HTML and use javascript to change it's source every 10 seconds.

For example:

```
<html>
<body>
<iframe id="theIframe" src="">

</iframe>
</body>
<script>
  function timeout() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("theIframe").src= 'http://www.google.com';
        timeout();
    }, 10000);
  }  
  timeout(); 

</script>
<html>
```

I am not sure this exact code will work because I just wrote it without test. But you can get the general idea. Like this every 10 seconds it will reload google. You can modify it so the websites are taken from an array or something.

Not all browsers will support opening the PDF directly in browser though. Some might want to download it - depending on plugins. If you want to render the PDF it might require external libraries.